# How to recognize relative addresses in python file when run by other processes?

Tags: python, schedule

When I run a python script with other process, all my relative addresses defined in my py script are not identified. How can I fix this issue?
I want use `crontab` to run any program but, the relative addresses in that file are not recognized.

Comment: what do you mean by "relative addresses"? Please elaborate on exactly what your issue is, ideally, providing some sort of [mcve] which demonstrates the problem

Comment: For example I defined ```addr = "./data"```. So, it cannot be recognized when run by another process.

Comment: What do you mean "so it cannot be recognized when run by another process"?

Comment: When I run the script by itself, all these relative addresses work fine. But when I run the script by another process, all relative addresses translate to the address of that parent process + relative address. Suppose your parent process resides in ```/Users/test/``` and the relative address in python file is ```./data/``` so, it translates to ```/Users/test/data/``` which does not exist.

Comment: OK. So a few things to clear up - you mean *path* not *address*, which made the question confusing. And being run in a different *process* doesn't break relative paths by itself, the issue is running with a *different working directory* --- having a different working directory would break the relative paths in the same process as well!

Comment: It is hard to say how to address this without more details. But one general approach would be to take a directory as an argument and use that argument to create absolute paths in the program